# Double hop issue with IIS and SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, iis-8

I'm running into the classic double hop problem with my intranet site that references the SSRS web service.  Here is the topology:

Client ->  Web Server -> SQL Server (DB and SSRS)

Here is what I have done so far:

- SPNs created for HTTP/webserver - NetBios and FQDN (domain user for the AppPool)
- SPNs for HTTP/sqlserver (domain user running SQL and SSRS)
- SPN for MSSQLSvc/sqlserver (domain user running SSRS)
- Web server and app pool's identity are allowed to delegate in AD
- Client account is allowed to be delegated
- Web server's web app is impersonating the client user and calling the SSRS web service, passing the DefaultNetworkCredentials and setting the ImpersonationLevel to Delegation

I get 401'ed at the SSRS service.  If I pass my personal credentials explicitly then everything works so I'm confident that my issue is just with delegating client credentials.

I feel like I've read 20 articles about this and have tried everything with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it.  I was setting the only Windows Authentication provider to Negotiate:Kerberos but if I did that before unchecking kernel mode, IIS Manager would helpfully remove Negotiate:Kerberos from the providers because it was invalid.  That left me with no providers and a guaranteed 401 at the middle website.

Once I got Kerberos forced then my Delegation started working and the SSRS web service worked as well.